# Bundler using different version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed ruby without using rvm. the paths and version for ruby are as follows:

[image]

But when i run bundle install, a fatal error occurs. It seems to use ruby version ruby1.9.1 from `/usr/local/lib/ruby1.9.1` instead of `usr/local/bin/ruby`. Following is the snapshot:

[image]

How to make bundle install use ruby 1.9.3p0 instead of 1.9.1?? Help!

Answer (score 0):

Run `rvm use ruby 1.9.3`

You have to specify ruby version in gemfile

`ruby '1.9.3'`

Then bundler will automatically detect the ruby version

Comment: I have installed ruby without using rvm.
And I cant create a new rails project also. Its throwing the above error.

Comment: Try `sudo bundle install`

Comment: :(, Try with RVM. `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --ruby=1.9.3` . https://github.com/Hack56/Rails-Template/wiki/Installing-Ruby-via-RVM-on-Ubuntu-Lucid-10.04

Answer (score 0):

Its not using the wrong version of ruby. Its just trying to install gems to that directory. The real reason you're having problems is because your user doesn't have permission (you can be sure by typing `whereis ruby`). Even if running command with sudo worked you would still find yourself having many problems in the future. The reason these issues never occur with RVM is because RVM automatically changes the gem environment variables for your user. For starters type `gem env` into your console. This will give you very important details about where rubygem searches for executables and paths.

Under the `GEM PATH` section I see:

- GEM PATHS:

  - /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global

whereas it appears that your ruby installation is looking in /usr/local/lib, which is probably write protected. If you don't want to install RVM then the true fix is to create a directory in your user's root to install gems to. Follow the first step from [this guide](http://kb.site5.com/ruby-on-rails/how-to-setup-a-custom-rubygems-environment/) to change your gem path.